# Logarithm of probability limit question

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X_1, X_2, ...$ be a sequence of i.i.d random vectors taking values in $\mathbb{R^n}$ such that $L(\lambda):= \log \mathbb{E} [e^{\langle \lambda, X_1 \rangle}] < \infty$ for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{R^n}$. We want to show that:
$$
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}  \epsilon \log \mathbb{P}(|X_1| \geq 1/\epsilon) = - \infty
$$
The hint suggests to include the event $\{|X_1| \geq 1/\epsilon\}$ within the union of $2n$ simpler one-dimensional events. If I'm not mistaken, then this would be, using the notation $X_1 = (X_{1,1},X_{1,2}, ... , X_{1,n})$
$$
\{|X_1| \geq 1/\epsilon\} \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^{n} \{ |X_{1,i}| \geq 1/n\epsilon\} = \bigcup_{i=1}^n \{ X_{1,i} \geq 1/n\epsilon\} \cup \{-X_{1,i} \geq 1/n\epsilon\}
$$
Then we would use monotonicity of $\mathbb{P}$ and try and work with this union. I was expecting to use the exponential version of Markov's inequality to get $L$ to pop out for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R^n}$, and then take the logarithm, however I don't get anywhere with this.

Answer (score 0):

Fix $c>0$. Take $X$ as one of the $X_{1,i}$ and write $$P(X \geq 1/\epsilon) = E[e^{cX}e^{-cX}1(X \geq 1/\epsilon)] = E[e^{cX}e^{-cX}1(e^{-cX} \leq e^{-c/\epsilon})]\leq e^{-c/\epsilon}Ee^{cX}.$$ Take logs on both sides and multiply by $\epsilon$ to deduce $$ \epsilon\log P(X \geq 1/\epsilon)\leq -c + \epsilon\log Ee^{cX}, $$ which is finite by assumption. Conclude $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\epsilon\log P(X \geq 1/\epsilon)\leq -c$, which can be made as small as desired by choosing $c$ large enough. Apply this argument to all $X_{1,i}$ in your union bound and switch the roles of $cX$ and $-cX$ for your $-X_{1,i}$.